# App crashes on screen rotation when trying to find menu item

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, screen-rotation

I am using a collapsingToolbarLayout in my application and as long as the menu is not collapsed there is no problem when rotating the phone. But when the menu is collapsed and only the original toolbar is showing the app crashes. The thing is, when only the original toolbar is showing a clickable item appears and disappears when the collapsing toolbar is shown. When rotating the phone, the application does not find this item. How can I solve this?

The activity where the menu is.

```
private Menu menu;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    ...
    AppBarLayout mAppBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout2);
    mAppBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new 
    AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {

            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int 
            verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    isShow = true;
                    showOption();
                } else if (isShow) {
                    isShow = false;
                    hideOption();
                }
            }
        });

    }

@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        this.menu = menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
        hideOption();
        return true;
    }

private void hideOption() {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
        item.setVisible(false);
    }

    private void showOption() {
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
        item.setVisible(true);
    }
```

The relevant code in xml-file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="128dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/nestedScrollView">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsTool"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorSecondary"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleGravity="bottom|center"
            app:expandedTitleMargin="16dp"
            app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display2"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:title="@string/title_expenses">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_action_exit"
                app:title="@string/title_expenses"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/background_light" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

The menu_Scrolling.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.journaldev.collapsingtoolbarlayout.ScrollingActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_info"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Add"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

This is the error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.korneliapalm.android.samboappen/com.korneliapalm.android.samboappen.MoneyListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3114)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5039)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4948)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.korneliapalm.android.samboappen.MoneyListActivity.showOption(MoneyListActivity.java:163)
        at com.korneliapalm.android.samboappen.MoneyListActivity.onCreate(MoneyListActivity.java:51)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7327)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7318)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3094)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3257) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5039) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4948) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1948) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please share your error logs, which the Android studio's Logcat is dumping.

Comment: That happens because when you rotate your activity gets created again. Hence when recreated your menu item is null.

Comment: How can I save my menu item then so it is not null when created again?

Comment: Take a look at the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in `onCreate` you are calling the methods `hideOption()` and `showOption()`. 
However, oncreate is called before `onCreateOptionsMenu` which is where you are inflating the menu view. So calling `menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);` triggers a null pointer.

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_scrolling, menu);
```

You need to ensure that the menu view is inflated before you call these two methods in onCreate.

```
private void hideOption() {
    if (menu == null) return;
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
    item.setVisible(false);
}

private void showOption() {
    if (menu == null) return;
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
    item.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Activity:**

When orientation change occurs,android restarts the running Activity ( onDestroy() is called, followed by onCreate()). If you want to handle inside activity,you cant use: in **manifest** file for **particular activity.**

For API 12 and below:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

if you are targeting API 13 or above

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: This is the last resort of handling orientations and isn't recommended by Google Developer documents. It is only recommended as the last resort, when no other options are left to implement.

Comment: also OP will then have to override the config changed method and handle everything. So if u are going to answer this, might as well give the full answer and not just his

Comment: Here you cant save menu item inside  variable.so

Comment: Yes there is several way for this .

Answer (score 0):

You have not handled orientations in your code. You should try to handle them.
The reason for your crash is that when you rotate your screen following event happens:

1. Activity gets destroyed.
2. Activity gets re-created.
3. AppBarLayout's offset gets changed and the method `onOffsetChanged` is called.
4. `if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {` condition gets true and `showOption();` method is called.
5. Because the Activity is being re-created, the menu item that is used in `showOption();` method is `null` on the line `MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);`
6. Because the `item` is null, the code `item.setVisible(true);` produces a runtime crash of `Null Pointer Exception`.

The proper way of handling orientations is to implement the following method in your Activity code:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation === Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "landscape", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    } else if (newConfig.orientation === Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "portrait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

As a pre-cautionary measure, you can add null checks for avoiding the crashes temporarily like this:

```
private void hideOption() {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
    if (item != null) {
        item.setVisible(false);
    } else {
        Log.e("Your Class", "hideOption() was called, but menu item was null");
    }
}

private void showOption() {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_info);
    if (item != null) {
        item.setVisible(true);
    } else {
        Log.e("Your Class", "showOption() was called, but menu item was null");
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Reference link:**
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes